# Can a Hyper-V host join a domain of a virtual machine domain controller on a different host?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine

This is a lab environment for a test, I need to join a Hyper-V host to a domain of a virtual machine domain controller on a different host. If doable, what is the prerequisite? Need to be in the same IP address section such as 168.21.74.xx?

Answer (score 0):

Yes a Hyper-V host can join a domain, if the DC happens to be a VM.  It shouldn't matter if it is hosted on the Hyper-V host, or another host.  It just needs to be on when the Hyper-V joins the domain.

The prerequisites are exactly the same as if the domain controller was physical.  The DC must be reachable via the network.  Being on the same subnet is usually enough.  It can be on another subnet, if you have name resolution, and routing setup properly.